# How to get a none type answer from the user?

Tags: python, input, nonetype

I am trying to get a none type input from the user in Python.
My program is that of a news channel, you write a period of time and it shows you the news of that period but I want my program to work so that if the user doesn't want to specify a period he presses enter instead of giving an answer and I want my program to automatically change the value to none if there is no answer but even if I don't answer the type will remain str.

i get the period of time by 2 variables. 1: starting point 2:ending point.I use methods to and from for this btw.

i tried to first by writing none as the variable value but that didnt work. then i tried to not answer but that didnt work now i need you guys help.I have around 10 variables and if i wanna do what i wanna do i will have to write 3 - 4 lines per variable making around 40 lines which will be:
if len(variable) == 0:
variable = None

i dont want to go through so much pain so please help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Is there a specific reason you need the value to be `None` and not some other falsy value?

Comment: Are you looking to do? `answer = input("Enter something ") or None`?

Comment: Try the above code and then follow it with `print(answer)`. If you just hit return at the prompt then it will print `None`

Comment: @JRiggles I am sorry if the question was hard to understand but i dont quite get what type of minimal reproducible example are you asking about

Comment: but how did it work like can you give me a little explanation because i have never seen or being used in any program nor has my teacher taught it. Or maybe he has and i was just not paying attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string looks "falsey" to python and thus we can use `or` to set an alternate value. In this case `None`.

Try:

```py
answer = input("Enter something ") or None
print(answer is None)
```

When prompted for a value, just hit return.

Comment: bro thanks If it werent for you i would have been writing 40 lines of code. Now I Dont Need One